# SharePoint site and list "stop Inheriting permission" button is inactive

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, permissions, inheritance

I  am using SharePoint 2013 and when I am going to set unique permission for sites and pages with SharePoint designer, every thing is working fine.

But when I am going to set unique permission for lists and libraries with manage list permissions in list setting, "stop Inheriting permission" button is inactive and there is no check box per group.

[image]

Note: I am using site collection administrator to this work

Comment: What is warning in the yellow color behind the dropdown? Try different browser...

Answer (score 1):

If you are a site collection admin and "Stop Inheriting Permissions" is disabled then its not a SharePoint permission issue. It could be

1. A web browser issue. Try different browser.
2. Try deleting the web browser cache/temporary internet files/cookies.
3. Try on a different machine with your login.

Comment: Thank you very much dear Ahmad , with google chrome it is working fine.